# Delete Akeneo attribute/entities values by API

Tags: akeneo

I need to delete some attribute values from Akeneo using API.

In the documentation I can't find any example on how to delete attribute and entities possible values.

This is the link of the documentation that I'm looking:

https://api.akeneo.com/api-reference.html#Referenceentityrecord

How can I deal with the DELETE of these values ?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 1):

There is no API endpoint to remove an attribute or a reference-entity record (and more generally, if there is nothing in the doc it means it doesn't exist)